# How do I add Tomcat server in Netbeans 8.0?

Tags: netbeans

I'm unable to see the servers tab services section in IDE 8.0 to add my tomcat server? How do i add my tomcat server?

I have tried all options possible to add a tomcat server and its not working.

Answer (score 3):

As @prince said, you sould be able to install it under

> **Window**->**Services** ->**Servers**(Shortcut: Ctrl + 5) ;Right Click -Add Server
>
> **Tools** -> **Servers** -> **Add Server**

that is assuming you have installed Netbeans with support for Java EE. Which might not be always the case.

In case you have installed the basic IDE, in order to be able to add a Tomcat Server you will have to install the **Java EE Base** plugin first.

Comment: I just installed Java EE Base and follow Tools -> Servers -> Add Server and here listing Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You can add servers from the service tab under Windows menu

**Window**->**Services** ->**Servers**(Shortcut: Ctrl + 5) ;Right Click -Add Server

**Tools** -> **Servers** -> **Add Server**